# Compare line by line in notepad++

Tags: comparison, text-editor, notepad++

> Consider a file which has a line like this:
>
> "STDHKD7" "STD" "PM" "HKD" 7 0 "" "" "" "" "" yes yes "FILE" "fx.csv"
>   yes no 0 1
>
> Next consider a file which has a line like this:
>
> "STDHKD7" "STD" "PM" "HKD" 7 0 "" "" "" "" "" yes yes "FILE" "fx.csv"
>   yes no 0 2

As you can see there is a difference in the end of 2 instead of 1. These lines are not on the same line in the document so I cannot use the default notepad++ comparison tool. I want to be able to take the first line some somehow "find a match" (maybe up to a certain number of characters) in the other file, no matter what line that match is on. This in order to find differences like the one highlighted above.

Comment: Did you find something ? I used the Compare plugin v1.5.6 : https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any notepad++ plugin solving your needs. 
I think you have to implement an own solution for this (script, plugins, ...).